# Configuring DAHDI channels

Tags: asterisk, voip, dahdi

I installed dahdi 2.7 and asterisk 11 on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. I'm having a hard time configuring a DAHDI channel. I have a AEX 808 card from Digium, the one with 8 FXO ports by my phone line is plugged into port 1 of the card.

I followed the exact same steps in http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/DAHDI
under the Sample Installation section except I edited dahdi_channels.conf to point to the same group number as the channel number for channels 2-8 as I thought asterisk was trying to make a call from a channel other than channel 1 since they were all previously in group=0.

Here are my config files:

chan_dahdi.conf:

```
[trunkgroups]

; No trunk groups are needed in this configuration.

[channels]
#include /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf
; The channels context is used when defining channels using the
; older deprecated method.  Don't use this as a section name.

;[phone](!)
;
; A template to hold common options for all phones.
;
usecallerid = yes
hidecallerid = no
callwaiting = no
;threewaycalling = yes
transfer = yes
echocancel = yes
echotraining = yes
immediate = no
```

dahdi_channels.conf:

```
; Autogenerated by /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf on Thu Aug  8 15:55:40 2013
; If you edit this file and execute /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf again,
; your manual changes will be LOST.
; Dahdi Channels Configurations (chan_dahdi.conf)
;
; This is not intended to be a complete chan_dahdi.conf. Rather, it is intended
; to be #include-d by /etc/chan_dahdi.conf that will include the global settings
;

; Span 1: WCTDM/0 "Wildcard AEX800" (MASTER) 
;;; line="1 WCTDM/0/0 FXSKS  (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=0
context=from-pstn
channel => 1
callerid=
group=
context=default

;;; line="2 WCTDM/0/1 FXSKS  (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=2
context=from-pstn
channel => 2
callerid=
group=
context=default

;;; line="3 WCTDM/0/2 FXSKS  (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=3
context=from-pstn
channel => 3
callerid=
group=
context=default

;;; line="4 WCTDM/0/3 FXSKS  (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=4
context=from-pstn
channel => 4
callerid=
group=
context=default

;;; line="5 WCTDM/0/4 FXSKS  (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=5
context=from-pstn
channel => 5
callerid=
group=
context=default

;;; line="6 WCTDM/0/5 FXSKS  (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=6
context=from-pstn
channel => 6
callerid=
group=
context=default

;;; line="7 WCTDM/0/6 FXSKS  (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=7
context=from-pstn
channel => 7
callerid=
group=
context=default

;;; line="8 WCTDM/0/7 FXSKS  (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)"
signalling=fxs_ks
callerid=asreceived
group=8
context=from-pstn
channel => 8
callerid=
group=
context=default
```

/etc/dahdi/system.conf:

```
# Autogenerated by /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf on Thu Aug  8 15:55:40 2013
# If you edit this file and execute /usr/sbin/dahdi_genconf again,
# your manual changes will be LOST.
# Dahdi Configuration File
#
# This file is parsed by the Dahdi Configurator, dahdi_cfg
#
# Span 1: WCTDM/0 "Wildcard AEX800" (MASTER) 
fxsks=1
echocanceller=mg2,1
fxsks=2
echocanceller=mg2,2
fxsks=3
echocanceller=mg2,3
fxsks=4
echocanceller=mg2,4
fxsks=5
echocanceller=mg2,5
fxsks=6
echocanceller=mg2,6
fxsks=7
echocanceller=mg2,7
fxsks=8
echocanceller=mg2,8
```

With these config files, when I start asterisk, I get the following DAHDI related errors:

```
[Aug  8 15:56:26] WARNING[25198] chan_dahdi.c: Unable to specify channel 1: Device or resource busy
[Aug  8 15:56:26] ERROR[25198] chan_dahdi.c: Unable to open channel 1: Device or resource busy
[Aug  8 15:56:26] ERROR[25198] chan_dahdi.c: Unable to register channel '1'
```

This is the result of lsdahdi from the unix terminal:

```
### Span  1: WCTDM/0 "Wildcard AEX800" (MASTER) 
  1 FXO        FXSKS       (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)  
  2 FXO        FXSKS       (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)  RED
  3 FXO        FXSKS       (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)  RED
  4 FXO        FXSKS       (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)  RED
  5 FXO        FXSKS       (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)  RED
  6 FXO        FXSKS       (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)  RED
  7 FXO        FXSKS       (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)  RED
  8 FXO        FXSKS       (In use) (EC: VPMOCT032 - INACTIVE)  RED
```

I'm not sure why it says "In use" as there are no calls currently being processed. I'm not sure if this is the default output for an AEX808 card. How can I get my DAHDI working with asterisk? What am I doing wrong?

Result of dahdi show status in asterisk:

```
 astersik*CLI> dahdi show status
 No such command 'dahdi show status' (type 'core show help dahdi show' for other possible commands)
```

Output of dahdi_cfg -vvvv:

```
DAHDI Tools Version - 2.7.0-rc1

DAHDI Version: 2.7.0-rc1
Echo Canceller(s): HWEC
Configuration
======================


Channel map:

Channel 01: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 01)
Channel 02: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 02)
Channel 03: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 03)
Channel 04: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 04)
Channel 05: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 05)
Channel 06: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 06)
Channel 07: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 07)
Channel 08: FXS Kewlstart (Default) (Echo Canceler: mg2) (Slaves: 08)

8 channels to configure.

Setting echocan for channel 1 to mg2
Setting echocan for channel 2 to mg2
Setting echocan for channel 3 to mg2
Setting echocan for channel 4 to mg2
Setting echocan for channel 5 to mg2
Setting echocan for channel 6 to mg2
Setting echocan for channel 7 to mg2
Setting echocan for channel 8 to mg2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `dahdi show status` in asterisk ?

Comment: Well, it seems that dahdi is not installed correctly in Asterisk :/ but you can check this link :http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=84728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much investigation, I realized that DAHDI wasn't installed properly. I removed DAHDI and asterisk from the system and reinstalled everything to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Check output of:

```
dahdi_cfg -vvvvv
```

Comment: So dahdi is ok. Check that asterisk user able access /dev/dahdi/*, if it ok - try recompile asterisk

Comment: Yes, asterisk user and /dev/dahdi owner are the same. Do you mean I should reinstall asterisk?

Comment: I tried recompiling using these steps...still says "Unable to configure channel 1 - Device or resource busy"- 
./configure
make
make install

Comment: digium offer support for cards. I think you need contact digium support,they can give you more info. I am sorry, there are no way remotly guess what you dooing wrong based on info you provided.